# C# multiuser security framework

Tags: c#, security, multi-user

I need to implement a security framework for a multiuser application that is in the design phase. I intend to use a Role based access control RBAC Security model (- BUT which can be further refined by the user adding additional privileges).

Are there any existing C# "security frameworks" that I can use (at least as a starting ground), or do I have to write it from scratch?

As an aside, I would prefer a "pure library" approach - as I don't want to be constrained to desktop or web application type using the security framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .NET framework makes it very easy to implement Role-Based security in your application. Enforcing security consists of two parts, Authentication and Authorization. The .NET framework provides access to the user through an identity and authorization access through a principal. Thread.CurrentPrinicpal gives you access to the current principal assigned to the executing thread.

You can implement role based security framework easily by using [IPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.aspx) and [IIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iidentity.aspx) interfaces.

[Here](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/security/article.php/c7415) is a complete example to create your RB security framework.